# Using personas in software development

Tags: project-management

We are using personas at work. However, is the use of quotes from the imaginary user a good thing to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personas are archetypes intended to model a class of users as a single, specific person. They're intended to communicate user needs clearly, and "engage the empathy of the design and development towards the human target of the design" [Alan Cooper, "About Face"].

You can convey the persona in multiple ways. I've usually seen third-party narrative. Cooper suggests a photographic collage as one way of multiple.

So the question is whether the quotes help convey the persona, and make a team feel driven to meet the needs of this archetype user and the actual users represented. If they do, then yes, using them is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

For creating a Persona, you can review the web site that SAP UX build for software builders at https://sapcsr.build.me/splashapp/learningDetail/644

There it is explicitely stated to:

**Create a short quote - real or pieced together from various real quotes - that illustrates the user's goals or motivations.**